# Class is not key value coding-compliant for the key fullName - tableView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiview

Hello :) This is my code :

myView.m is loaded from an xib

```
- (void)loadData {


    self.players = [model.dbManager.playersDbManager selectAllEntities];

    [self.PlayersTableView reloadData];
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {

    return self.players.count; 
}


- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {


    CustomPopOverCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"MyCell"];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[CustomPopOverCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"MyCell"];
    }
    // Configure the cell...
    Player *p = (Player *)[self.players objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.fullName.text = p.firstName;
    cell.number.text = (NSString *)p.jerseyNumber;

    return cell;

}
```

myCustomCell.h :

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *number;

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *fullName;
```

myVC where I load xib :

```
self.popover = [[TaggingPopOver alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, contentContainer.frame.size.width, contentContainer.frame.size.height)];
    [UIViewHelper showView:self.popover InCenterOfView:contentContainer];
    self.popover.delegate = self;
    [self.popover.PlayersTableView registerNib:[UINib nibWithNibName:@"Cell" bundle:nil] forCellReuseIdentifier:@"MyCell"];
    [self.popover loadData];
```

[This is the xib of customcell.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2goxw.png)

I try to load fullname + number into my custom cell but I get an error

> class is not key value coding-compliant  for the key fullName

I tried everything but nothing works. Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: It doesn't seem like your IBOutlets are hooked up to your cell's XIB

Comment: Which class is giving the error?

Comment: Maybe now but IBOutlets were linked and was same error :/ I tried everything.

I turned on exception breakpoint and this line gives error :  cell.fullName.text = p.firstName;

Comment: Unrelated to your question: you really don’t want to be using different .xib files for different screen sizes.

Comment: Its created cuz Auto-Layaout isnt doing well with font size etc. It was a top-down.

Comment: Copy the entire error message from the Xcode debug console, and paste it into your question. You have not included the complete error message.

Comment: @robmayoff My problem is solved. I created custom init in my .xib subclass + method to load .xib/view

Answer (score 1):

Are you registering your cell ID?

```
    UINib*          cellNib = [UINib nibWithNibName: self.cellID bundle: nil];
    NSAssert(cellNib != nil, @"Cell nib %@ doesn’t exist", self.cellID);
    [aTableView registerNib: cellNib forCellReuseIdentifier: self.cellID];
```

or set that up in the .xib file.

Comment: Yes. In xib cell identifire  = MyCell

Comment: Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<NSObject 0x12995b760> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key fullName.' Full error

Comment: But how does the UITableView know which cellID?

Comment: It could be a point.What is the best way to do it ? Always I set it in storyboard when i have UITbaleViewController.

Comment: Aaaa I used it in my code :
 [self.popover.PlayersTableView registerNib:[UINib nibWithNibName:@"Cell" bundle:nil] forCellReuseIdentifier:@"MyCell"];

Answer (score 1):

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {


    CustomPopOverCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"MyCell"];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[CustomPopOverCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"MyCell"];
    }
    // Configure the cell...
    Player *p = (Player *)[self.players objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.fullName.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",p.firstName];
    cell.number.text = (NSString *)p.jerseyNumber;

    return cell;

}
```

Comment: Unfortunately it doesnt :(

Answer (score 0):

For me this turned out to be an object in the .xib file referencing (with the old name) an IBOutlet property in the controlling class that had been renamed.

i.e. I had renamed the IBOutlet property in the controller and failed to update the connection in the .xib file.